# Making CrystalReportViewer maximised mode

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystalreportViewer for my application to generate reports. I want to add some other controls like Textbox and Button control.

I have been able to add the controls and I set the Dock property of CrystalViewer to Fill. The other controls like Button and Textbox needs to be on the upperpart of the screen and the viewer to follow but with the Dock property set to FILL, it places the controls on the viewer. If I set the Dock property to None, it does not maximize at runtime.

Comment: I think by what you're describing that instead of Dock, you want to size the CRViewer where you want it on the form and then set the `Anchor` property to `Top, Bottom, Left,Right`. This will then stretch the viewer was the window resizes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set autosize to true.

Comment: I cheched with my programming. When autosize is set to true and the dock property is set to fill, you get an form sized cr viewer without docking it.